# Is there any application of Banach fixed point theorem in number theory?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, soft-question, fixed-point-theorems

Is there any application of Banach fixed point theorem in number theory? I have seen some applications in integral equations and economics. I am curious about number theory.

Comment: Possibly in the p-adic numbers , but apart from that I guess not.

Comment: A small example here: the Banach fixed point theorem can be used to prove the existence of the Teichmuller character: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3823717/232